# Meteor publication error - Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors

Tags: meteor

I have this publication

```
Meteor.publish('temsInThisCompetition', function (id) {
var teams = [];
return Competitions.find(id).fetch().map(function (doc) {
    for(var item in doc.teams){
        teams.push(Teams.find(item));
    }
    return teams;
});
});
```

But I am getting this error

```
 Exception from sub temsInThisCompetition id kDPuEbc9dtWn2tfT3 Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me

```
Meteor.publish('teamsInThisCompetition', function (id) {
var competition = Competitions.findOne(id);
return Teams.find({_id:{$in:competition.teams}});
});
```

Comment: Note that if a team is added to or removed from a competition, the publication will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since Meteor is asynchronous, your initial code doesn't work because the team array is returned before the for loop is completed.

If you need a for loop in an async environment, you could use a callback function, like this:

```
function getTeams(id, callback) {
    Competitions.find(id).fetch().map(function (doc) {

        var teams = [];

        for(var item in doc.teams){
            teams.push(Teams.find(item));

            if(teams.length==doc.teams.length) {
                callback(teams);
            }
        }
    });
}

Meteor.publish('temsInThisCompetition', function (id) {
    getTeams(id, function(teams) {
        return teams;
    });    
});
```

Collection.find() without a callback and Collection.findOne() are synchronous, that's why the code in your answer doesn't return an empty set.